# Loop/if else in R for data frame

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I am really stuck on doing a loop in R. I have tried using ifelse too, but just can't seem to get a result.

I have a data frame as follows which shows a customer ID, their date of travel, mode and journey start time:

```
ID     |  Date     |   Mode  |  Time
------ | --------- | ------- | -----
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  120 
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  130
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  290
1234   | 12/10/16  | Train   |  310
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  330
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  220 
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  230
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  290
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  450
4567   | 14/10/16  | Train   |  1000
```

So on 12/10, customer 1234 made 4 bus jnys and 1 train jny.

I want to create a 5th column which identifies if the journey stages are linked i.e. is the 2nd journey linked to the 1st journey, is the 3rd journey linked to the 2nd journey (where 1=linked, 0=not linked).

The following conditions need to apply:

- the jnys are for the same person and take place on the same day
- 2 bus journeys are within 60 mins of one another (so a bus and train journey within 60 mins of one another would not be linked)
- if the i+1th and the ith journey are linked, then the i+1th journey cannot be linked to the i+2th journey

I would like the output to be as follows:

```
ID     |  Date     |   Mode  |  Time  | Linked
------ | --------- | ------- | -----  | -----
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  120   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  130   |  1
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  290   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Train   |  310   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  330   |  0
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  220   |  0
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  230   |  1
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  290   |  0
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  450   |  0
4567   | 14/10/16  | Train   |  1000  |  0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Showing any effort by yourself would be much appreciated!

Comment: I literally haven't got anywhere with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Grothendieck's answer, but it may not be as easy to interpret for someone new to R. So lets do it in a less programatically efficient way that shows you the steps to take. I'll use the same data frame naming convention as Grothendieck.

Lets determine if the time between journeys is within 60 minutes. Lets loop through all rows in the data frame and if they are the same account and if they are the same type of Mode then check if they are less than 60 minutes apart and if all three conditions check out then set linked to 1. Otherwise, we'll set linked to 0.

```
for (i in 2:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$ID[i]==df$ID[i-1]){
    if (df$Mode[i]==df$Mode[i-1]){
      if ((df$Time[i]-df$Time[i-1]) < 60){
        df$linked[i] <- 1
      }
      else {
        df$linked[i] <- 0
      }
    }
    else {
      df$linked[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  else {
    df$linked[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: don't you want `df$linked[i]` rather than `df$linked` ?  Also: +1 for logic, but do note that this is likely to be **many** times slower than @G.Grothendieck's answer ...

Comment: Sure `G. Grothendieck` can be made less criptic, but R actually encourages you to use vectorized operations such as `diff()` and `cumsum()`. Vectorized operations can also be easy to interpret for someone new to R.

Comment: This is what I was trying out, however, I cannot get it to work because it the error says:

Comment: Error: unexpected '<' in:
"      if (df$MODE[i]==df$MODE[i-1])          {
        if (df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1])<"

Comment: I have amended this slightly, but every record returns a 1 in the linked column. I'm not sure why as I thought this seemed like the logical approach. I adapted to use 'and' statements , but still got the same thing

Comment: As Ben Bolker explained, every `df$linked` should be changed to `df$linked[i]`.

Comment: JassiL, in the comment: 
Error: unexpected '<' in: " if (df$MODE[i]==df$MODE[i-1]) { if (df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1])<" 
The parenthetical expression for the if closes too early:
Error: unexpected '<' in: " if (df$MODE[i]==df$MODE[i-1]) { if ((df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1])<60)"

Comment: I used JJFord's answer and amended slightly - thanks for the response, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

**1) ave** Try this:

```
transform(DF, linked = ave(Time, ID, Date, cumsum(c(FALSE, Mode[-1] != Mode[-nrow(DF)])), 
      FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x) < 60)))
```

giving:

```
     ID     Date  Mode Time linked
1  1234 12/10/16   Bus  120      0
2  1234 12/10/16   Bus  130      1
3  1234 12/10/16   Bus  290      0
4  1234 12/10/16 Train  310      0
5  1234 12/10/16   Bus  330      0
6  4567 12/10/16   Bus  220      0
7  4567 12/10/16   Bus  230      1
8  4567 13/10/16   Bus  290      0
9  4567 13/10/16   Bus  450      0
10 4567 14/10/16 Train 1000      0
```

**2) sqldf**  Here is a solution using sqldf.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, coalesce(a.ID = b.ID and 
                            a.Date = b.Date and 
                            a.Mode = b.Mode and 
                            a.Time < b.Time + 60, 0) linked 
       from DF a left join DF b on a.rowid = b.rowid + 1")
```

**3) data.table**  Note that data.table tends to be both fast and memory efficient and may be able to handle data sizes in memory that other approaches cannot.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(DF)
dt[, linked := (Time < shift(Time, fill = -60) + 60) * 
               (Mode == shift(Mode, fill = Mode[1])), by = "ID,Date"]
```

**4) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   group_by(ID, Date) %>%
   mutate(linked = (Time < lag(Time, default = -Inf) + 60) * 
                   (Mode == lag(Mode, default = Mode[1]))) %>%
   ungroup()
```

giving a similar answer.

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- 
"ID     |  Date     |   Mode  |  Time
------ | --------- | ------- | -----
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  120 
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  130
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  290
1234   | 12/10/16  | Train   |  310
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  330
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  220 
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  230
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  290
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  450
4567   | 14/10/16  | Train   |  1000"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE,
 comment = "-", as.is = TRUE)
```

**Update:** Fixed.

Comment: Appreciate the response - is there a way I can avoid reading the table in? The table is quite big so this doesn't feel like the right thing to do

Comment: R only works with data frames in memory so you have to load the data. If your data is in a database, you can try to use for example the `dplyr` package. It translate R statements to SQL run inside the database connection and then only return the subset that interests you.

Comment: Have added an sqldf solution.  As it stands it assumes DF is in memory but you could likely adapt the SQL to your database setup whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
    # The journeys are for the same person, take place on the same day
    # and on the same mode of transport
    group_by(ID, Date, Mode) %>% 
    # 2 bus journeys are within 60 mins of one another 
    mutate(linked0 = c(Inf, diff(Time))<60, 
           # if the i+1th and the ith journey are linked, 
           # then the i+1th journey cannot be linked to the i+2th journey
           linkedsum = cumsum(linked0),
           linked = ifelse(linkedsum==1, linked0, 0))

      ID     Date  Mode  Time linked0 linkedsum linked
   <int>    <chr> <chr> <int>   <lgl>     <int>  <dbl>
1   1234 12/10/16   Bus   120   FALSE         0      0
2   1234 12/10/16   Bus   130    TRUE         1      1
3   1234 12/10/16   Bus   290   FALSE         1      0
4   1234 12/10/16 Train   310   FALSE         0      0
5   1234 12/10/16   Bus   330    TRUE         2      0
6   4567 12/10/16   Bus   220   FALSE         0      0
7   4567 12/10/16   Bus   230    TRUE         1      1
8   4567 13/10/16   Bus   290   FALSE         0      0
9   4567 13/10/16   Bus   450   FALSE         0      0
10  4567 14/10/16 Train  1000   FALSE         0      0
```

To perform this inside a database, see the [dplyr database vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).